# Giving access to the object tree to external files

Tags: go

Suppose I have a following structure of .go files inside the module:

- tree_definition.go
- tree_creation.go

The tree_creation parses some file and creates and object tree from it (otree for short) using data structures and methods (as well as functions) defined in tree_definition.
During the parsing I see external.go file that contains some code, that aims to access otree and modify it.
After the parsiing is complete, the code in external.go should be able to use otree through the API I defined in tree_definition and modify it. It all happens during the runtime.
For clarifications:

- Yes, I'm trying to replicate the behavior of the DOM
- The external.go comes from another directory, not from inside the module
- The external.go is visible only during the runtime when tree_creation adds external.go mention to the data structure of otree

I've completed almost all the steps to replicate it. This is the last part. Sadly, I cannot provide the link to the Git at the moment so you could see it yourself, but I would appreciate every comment that can help me clarify the situation.
Best regards!
I think I get an idea. I'll post it later.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "...external.go is visibly only during runtime..". However, it sounds like all you need to do is export those symbols that you want to access from another package. Did you try this and it didn't work? Show some code.

Comment: @BurakSerdar , I mean that external.go is provided in the file that has been parsed by tree_creation during execution. Yes, I've tried to implement plugins, but it works only "kind of". There is too much of a text necessary to write a plugin. On my side, I'm trying to replicate the behavior of JavaScript relatively to DOM. It doesn't require to communicate somehow or be pre-built. It just accessing API directly. I'll continue in the next comment.

Comment: @BurakSerdar , So I see 1 possible solution: I can place this module with all APIs on Git and import it "on-the-fly". Then, inside external.go, I can use provided APIs to build an object tree and use it directly in the runtime of external.go. Later, I'll add View API support to module so it can create a window as well. And also, I'll get rid of inclusion of external go files in the parsable file, so "one file to rule them all" will be presented.

Comment: Are you trying to write an interpreter? Show code.

Comment: @BurakSerdar , kind of)) I'm trying to build a browser. The parser and builder of the DOM-like object tree is ready. Next step is to include the feature of JavaScript. This feature is to access DOM and modify it, yet no imports required. I'm starting to think that I can build small service to build and execute go files. And this service will be invoked via goroutine from the main file, so it can give us the tabs-like behavior.

Comment: @BurakSerdar , so the structure will look like: browser.go (provides runtime and can build and execute go files), api.go (provides an interface to parse some file and create an object tree), user.go (that provides the code to use api.go). So when you make a "request" to browser.go, it builds and executes provided user.go. Also, api.go will provide a mechanism to pass object tree to the browser.go so that could display it

Comment: There is no ideal way to do this, plugins is the halfway sane way. You probably should redesign.

Comment: @Volker , Unexpectedly, I've discovered the memory-mapped files, and it can help me a lot. It allocates memory and lets another process to access and modify it. I can create a management system for a slice of such mmaps. Then, it will be easy to create such mmaps on demand and use it to communicate commands with object tree. I think that's a solution.

Comment: @Volker , and I could even make two-way communication. One to send commands to API, and second to get results back. I wonder what is the speed of truncating mmaps.. is it slower to allocate big enough map from the start, or to truncate it every time to the necessary size

Comment: One way of doing this is to create multiple executables and have them communicate via an RPC mechanism, like gRPC. Since all executables are on the same host, communication speed is usually tolerable. Here's a rather large example of how I did it once via gRPC: https://github.com/bserdar/watermelon

Comment: @BurakSerdar , wow) Thank you! You should post this as an answer, I'll check it as solution. At the end, I come to the following: I can execute (exec.Command) the code that I found during the parsing, using 2 prepared mem files as args. Those code should import "client-side" API that will decode commands into the format that "server-side" API understands and place them into the memory file. Same goes on the other side, the "server-side" API accepts commands and makes necessary calls. Also it provides responces that "client-side" API can decode and assign to the variables or as an error.

Comment: @BurakSerdar , anyway, I'll check your code in more details, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Okay, here we go!**
Finally, with the help of my pal, Bing Chat, I was able to find simple solution without using memory files or HTTP requests via localhost. Presented solution is elegant and works perfectly for me!
I still think I'll use the memory file, but we'll see. It depends on scalability.
Also, special thanks to

> @BurakSerdar

for his answer.

```
package main

// This will be in the runtime file
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "run", "user_defined.go")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        if scanner.Text() == "some_command" {
            fmt.Println("found some_command")
        }
        if scanner.Text() == "another_command" {
            fmt.Println("found another_command")
        }
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

EDIT 1
Turns out there is 3 ways of communicating between processes, but the best suited for my problem - Shared Memory.